# Draw line from centre of screen through mouse cursor to edge of screen

Tags: python, math, pygame, coordinates

I need a simple piece of code that takes two coordinates (centre of the screen, say `(450,450)` and the position of the cursor) and draws a line through the two points to the edge of the screen. I know you can use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` to find the position of the mouse; it is just the maths part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this has 6 downvotes?

Comment: I imagine that you could have provided more detail with the question. Maybe some code that you were working with, or a picture that illustrated what you were trying to do. But, that being said, it does not deserve 6 downvotes.

Comment: It could be because of the line *"I need a simple piece of code"*, which suggest that you're not interested in learning the algorithm but instead just want people to write code for you without you having to do any effort. This premise is strengthen because you don't provide any indication of what you've tried or researched. And getting 2-3 downvotes usually creates a snowball-effect where other users who are on the edge of maybe not downvoting puts a downvote since it's confirmed by other people that the question deserves it.

Comment: An example of some code, like an experiment with your variable, usually helps to narrow down abstract requests, like "simple" and upon feeling aversion we fail to answer. Please add your variables, like, `x_0`, `y_0`, `x` and `y` for mouse position, test one side of screen, like left and show a couple lines with your `if`s and calculus and it can be a game changer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a whirl:

```
# calculate angle in radians between center and mouse
angle = math.atan2(center.y - mouse.y, center.x - mouse.x)

# adjust to screen edge
edge_point.x = center.x + (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) * math.cos(angle)
edge_point.y = center.y + (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) * math.sin(angle)

# draw line
pygame.draw.line(surface,color, center, edge_point, width)
```

you can also increase the SCREEN_WIDTH to draw a little bit past the edge of the screen. Also, it is assumed that SCREEN_WIDTH is the longer of the width and height. If the Height is longer, choose height. Basically you just need a value that is past the edge of the screen.

Depending on the setup, the line may be drawn mirror image to where the mouse is. switch angle calculation to:

```
angle = math.atan2(mouse.y - center.y, mouse.x - center.x)
```

Comment: closest answer so far. it almost works, but the line is drawn on the opposite side of the screen to the mouse cursor. also, it does not reach the edge

Comment: you can increase the SCREEN_WIDTH a little to act as a buffer so it goes a little past the edge. As far as the opposite side, try switching the atan2 calculation to: (mouse.y - center.y, mouse.x - center.x)

Comment: Happy to help. I will update my answer to reflect my comments

Answer (score 0):

From [Pygame's documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos):

> pygame.mouse.get_pos()
>
> *get the mouse cursor position*
>
> `get_pos() -> (x, y)`
>
> Returns the X and Y position of the mouse cursor. The position is
>   relative the the top-left corner of the display. The cursor position
>   can be located outside of the display window, but is always
>   constrained to the screen.

As you see `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` outputs a tuple, `(x,y)`.

So, you can use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]` for the `x` component, and `pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]` for the `y` component.

## Edit:

Use `pygame.draw.line()`

Its documentation:

> pygame.draw.line()
>
> *draw a straight line segment*
>
> `line(Surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect`
>
> Draw a straight line segment on a Surface. There are no endcaps, the
>   ends are squared off for thick lines.

So you can do:

```
pygame.draw.line(surface,color,(sizeScreenX/2,sizeScreenY/2),pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

Where `suface`, `color`, `sizeScreenX` and `sizeScreenY` are already defined, matching your needs.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood my question. Read it again.

Comment: What you want to calculate? I thought you wanted to know how to find the cursor position for use with `pygame.draw.line()`. I'll edit my answer if you tell me exactly what you want to find.

Comment: It's in the title; I want to draw a line from the centre of the screen, *through* the mouse cursor, and to the edge of the screen. The dimensions for the screen are 900,900

Comment: No. As I have repeatedly stated, it needs to go *through* the cursor to the edge of the screen

Comment: Which edge of the screen? From the left to the right, from the upper right corner to the lower left corner. **You cannot determine a line with just one point**

Comment: What you want is to continue from both sides the line I was proposing?

Comment: I am not trying to determine a line **with just one point.** You have **2** points: the **centre** and the **cursor position**

Answer (score 0):

You have two points P0 and P1. They define line in parametric way:

```
 X = P0.X + t * (P1.X - P0.X)
 Y = P0.Y + t * (P1.Y - P0.Y)
```

find parameters t when X reaches screen border - `X=0` or `X=width`, and when Y reaches screen border -  `Y=0` or `Y=height` and calculate points at edges

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what t is or how to calculate it

Comment: t is parameter. t=0 corresponds to poiont P0, t=1 - to P1. To calculate t, solev simple eqiations like `P0.X + t * (P1.X - P0.X) = width`